# How to link to GSL library?

Tags: c, unix, shared-libraries, linker-errors

I have followed the instructions [on this site to](https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/jild13/2016/07/11/hello/) install GSL 2.7.1:

```
gcc -Wall -I/opt/gsl/include -c main.c
gcc -L/opt/gsl/lib main.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -o main
chmod +x ./main
```

When I try to run the program it exits with the following error:

> ./main: error while loading shared libraries: libgsl.so.27: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Here's the output from `ls -al /opt/gsl/lib` (as non-root user, i.e. 'other')

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 Jul  6 12:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root     4096 Jul  6 12:05 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 26382732 Jul  6 12:05 libgsl.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2345554 Jul  6 12:05 libgslcblas.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      946 Jul  6 12:05 libgslcblas.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       20 Jul  6 12:05 libgslcblas.so -> libgslcblas.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       20 Jul  6 12:05 libgslcblas.so.0 -> libgslcblas.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1429728 Jul  6 12:05 libgslcblas.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      915 Jul  6 12:05 libgsl.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       16 Jul  6 12:05 libgsl.so -> libgsl.so.27.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       16 Jul  6 12:05 libgsl.so.27 -> libgsl.so.27.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 15920320 Jul  6 12:05 libgsl.so.27.0.0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Jul  6 12:05 pkgconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a new file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/gsl.conf` and put in a single line `/opt/gsl/lib`. After that I ran `sudo ldconfig -v` and the library appeared. This is, because although the linking in itself worked, the executable did not know about the path.